# Iomega NAS ix2-200 RAID mode questions?

Tags: hard-drive, network-attached-storage, swap, raid1

I am looking forward to buy a NAS. Now I have found one which looks quiet interesting, it's the "[Iomega StorCenter NAS ix2-200 4.0 TB](http://go.iomega.com/en-us/products/network-storage-desktop/storcenter-network-storage-solution/network-hard-drive-ix2-200/?partner=4760#overviewItem_tab)". I will use it to store Mac OS X TimeMachine Backups and as a file storage over the network. But I am wondering if the NAS can do following.

When run in RAID1, there are two discs (A & B) in the NAS. Disk A will mirror to disk B.

Is it possible to exchange disk B through a disk C during running operations of the NAS without disturbance or damage?

Will disk A mirror itself automatically to Disk C after this action?

Can I access the data on Disk B after this action, as if it were a normal Hard-disk outside of the NAS?

In case that both disks in the NAS fail, can I remove them and insert disk B back into the NAS to mirror it to a new disk inside the NAS?

BONUS QUESTION: Has this disk removing procedure have a special name?

Comment: Have you tried asking IOmega, since it's their product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had experience on that precise model but generally the answer to all your questions is YES for every nas like that.

Even the last question should be yes because the nas should be capable to rebuilt the array from the meta information stored in the disk and also because a mirror raid is not that hard to be rebuild.

If you extract a running disk you can mount it on another host (the filesystem used by Iomega should be XFS, so every linux can mount it).

Bonus question: If I understand well what you mean, the action is SWAP. Hot swap is when you can exctract a disk without turning off the device. This Iomega is not hot swap.

Apart this in the recent past (*last 3 years*) we sold 12 Iomega Storcentre nas. We had 100% warranty emergencies on them: broken disks, bugs in the GUI, broken power units. We stopped to sell Iomega for this reason. I don't mean that this model is affected too but I would suggest you Buffalo http://www.buffalo-technology.com.